# href in Thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a SpringBoot app with the appContext `platsBruts`, but I don't know how to set the href withous hardcoding the appContext, none of the below examples works

```
<a th:href="/*[[@{/pistoles/list/}]]*/" class="pure-menu-link">
```

with the error :

```
Could not parse as expression: ="/*[[@{/pistoles/list/}]]*/"
```

or

```
<a href="/pistoles/list/}" class="pure-menu-link">
```

Comment: are you using thymeleaf ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you are using thymeleaf or not. If you are using thymeleaf, this should work

```
<a th:href= "@{/pistoles/list/}" class="pure-menu-link">
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you just had mistyped the "/}" in the end href value.

```
<a href="/pistoles/list/}" class="pure-menu-link">
```

Try this:

```
<a th:href="@{/pistoles/list}" class="pure-menu-link">
```

But make sure to have the thymeleaf namespace below included on top of html file for it to work.

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```